# Distance to a plane

Tags: c#, debugging, math, geometry, xna

I've written a simple little helper method whoch calculates the distance from a point to a plane. However, it seems to be returning nonsensical results. The code i have for creating a plane is thus:

```
Plane = new Plane(vertices.First().Position, vertices.Skip(1).First().Position, vertices.Skip(2).First().Position);
```

Fairly simple, I hope you'll agree. It creates an XNA plane structure using three points.

Now, immediately after this I do:

```
foreach (var v in vertices)
{
    float d = Math.Abs(v.ComputeDistance(Plane));
    if (d > Constants.TOLERANCE)
        throw new ArgumentException("all points in a polygon must share a common plane");
}
```

Using the same set of vertices I used to construct the plane, I get that exception thrown! Mathematically this is impossible, since those three points must lie on the plane.

My ComputeDistance method is:

```
public static float ComputeDistance(this Vector3 point, Plane plane)
{
    float dot = Vector3.Dot(plane.Normal, point);
    float value = dot - plane.D;
    return value;
}
```

AsI understand it, this is correct. So what could I be doing wrong? Or might I be encountering a bug in the implementation of XNA?

Some example data:

```
Points:
{X:0 Y:-0.5000001 Z:0.8660254}
{X:0.75 Y:-0.5000001 Z:-0.4330128}
{X:-0.75 Y:-0.5000001 Z:-0.4330126}

Plane created:
{Normal:{X:0 Y:0.9999999 Z:0} D:0.5} //I believe D should equal -0.5?

Distance from point 1 to plane:
1.0
```

Comment: What is the value of `Constants.TOLERANCE`?

Comment: However, tolerance isn't the issue. As you can see from the new example data I just edited in the distance is relatively vast.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that your `Plane` is implemented so that `D` is not the projection of one of your points onto the plane normal, but rather the negative of this. You can think of this as projecting a vector *from* the plane *to* the origin onto the normal.

In any case, I believe that changing

```
float value = dot - plane.D;
```

to

```
float value = dot + plane.D;
```

should fix things. HTH.

Comment: My goodness, that's so obvious once you say it! Thankyou so much.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'm not totally sure I understand the math here, but I suspect (based on formulas from http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-PlaneDistance.html among others) that

```
float value = dot - plane.D;
```

should actually be

```
float value = dot / plane.D;
```

EDIT: Ok, as mentioned in comments below, this didn't work.  My best suggestion then is to go look at the link or google "distance between a point and a plane" and try implementing the formula a different way.

Comment: I was working from this answer here which expresses it in pretty simple terms: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/xnaframework/thread/226600b4-0de4-4bac-bc55-a4d9b84dd92f

Comment: @Martin: Ok, it does look like you're following that suggestion correctly. However, that formula doesn't match any of the three or four other sites I've seen explaining this calculation.  Could you try my idea, just to humor me?

Comment: distance changes from 1.0 to 1.03, not a vast change and no improvement ;)

Comment: No worries, it has me completely stumped too :/ Btw, do you agree that D is wrong in the example i posted?

Comment: I'm not sure, especially since I don't know how D is supposed to be calculated.  3D math was never my strong point.